# Change linear x-axis to circular x-axis

Tags: python, coordinates

I have a series of numbers from 0 to 360 that I want to plot on the x-axis. The x-axis should be "circular", ie there should be no negative numbers before zero, but 359 instead of -1, 358 instead of -2, etc.
I would like a plot whose x-axis goes from 320 to 40, something like:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/zASYn.jpg

I don't want to manually change the data and the ticks on the axes, but I'd like to know if there is a more direct way, keeping the data as it is.

Comment: There doesn't seem to exist a direct `matplotlib.pyplot` one-liner for this, but you could write your own. Your last sentence, "I don't want to manually...", is pretty vague. It sounds like you're aware of functions like `ax.get_xticks` and `ax.set_xticklabels` but don't want to use them for some unstated reason? You could write a function that reads the ticks, applies the wanted modulo to them, and sets the labels.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's pretty simple. You need to use `%`, known as the modulo operator. This is how you'll convert your x axis numbers:

```
# Say your numbers are like these:
xaxis = [-1, -2, 600, 200, 360, 0, 6]

mod_xaxis = [x % 360 for x in xaxis]
# mod_xaxis is now [359, 358, 240, 200, 0, 0, 6]
```

Comment: My numbers are already like this, I want to change the axis, not the numbers...

Comment: Your question is not clear. Please add more context and details. Add some code too, if that can help clarify.